# Traefik memory consuming is unstable. Is that from misconfiguration?

Tags: docker, memory-leaks, config, traefik

At morning i opened a metrics of my server and find out that some service is not working well and consuming not a constant amount of RAM. After some investigations find out traefik memory usage is not statble.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MY64e.png)

Server is not in production and before it has been working statble for a week. Now there is no requests and load on server. I think this is not correct way of working traefik.

Latest feature implemented on the server has some code for programmatically change dynamic config file of traefik.

All services runnning on docker containers. Some traefik configs are from docker some from files.

Can some body explain why that happens? Is that happening because of dual access for dynamic config files?

I haven't tried anything yet to change that. Just trying to understant whats happenig.